# Exemplo simples de como gerar um arquivo XML no Oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, pl-sql, xsd

Alguém teria um exemplo simples de uma Procedure PLSQL (ou local da documentação) para gerar um arquivo XML com base em um Schema (xsd) , os dados seriam gerados a partir de uma consulta SQL. 
Na realidade arquivos do RPS da ANS (Agência Nacional de Saúde BR).

Comment: Veja se ajuda você esta [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7316610/5429980).

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas formas de gerar um `XML` no `PL-SQL`. Porém no caso do `XSD`, imagino que você deverá fazer uma validação de `Schema`. Então vou dividir a resposta em duas partes, primeiro em exemplos de geração de `XML` e por fim a validação do `Schema`.

Opções para gerar o `XML`:

#### 1. DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR

Este exemplo utiliza `CLOB` para armazenar o stream que será o arquivo `XML` e depois o mesmo é criado e salvo na pasta indicada utilizando o pacote `DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR`.

```
DECLARE
 varClob     CLOB;
 varString   VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN
 -- Abre a instancia do CLOB e o coloca em modo de escrita
 dbms_lob.createtemporary(varClob, TRUE);
 dbms_lob.open(varClob, dbms_lob.lob_readwrite);

 -- Variável string para armazenar parte do XML
 varString := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' ||
              '<root>' ||
              '<teste>Este é um teste</teste>' ||
              '</root>';

 -- Cria um XML simples de testes, pode ser dado quantos APPEND quiser e
 -- ir montando o XML durante sua rotina PL/SQL
 dbms_lob.writeappend(varClob, LENGTH(varString), varString);

 -- Aqui irá de fato gerar o arquivo físico do XML
 DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.CLOB2FILE(varClob, '/minha/pasta/', 'teste.xml', NLS_CHARSET_ID('UTF8'));

 -- Liberar dados do CLOB da memória
 dbms_lob.close(varClob);
 dbms_lob.freetemporary(varClob);
END;
```

Note que neste exemplo não existe nenhum parse, ou seja, o `XML` é gerado de forma bruta e qualquer anormalidade não será validada e consequentemente um `XML` inválido, uma solução mais refinada seria efetuar o parse do `CLOB` para evitar que alguma falha no `XML` comprometesse um processo posterior. Será visto no item 4.

#### 2. Pacote XMLGEN

Outra forma muito simples para gerar um documento `XML` é o uso do pacote `XMLGEN`. A função `getXml()` pega os parâmetros para a consulta `SQL` e o tipo de metadados (como DTD) e retorna um `CLOB` contendo o documento `XML`.

```
SELECT xmlgen.getXml(
  'SELECT empno "EMP_NO"
        , ename "NAME"
        , deptno "DEPT_NO"
     FROM emp
    WHERE deptno = 10'
  , 0
  ) FROM dual;
```

Resultado:

```
<?xml version = '1.0'?>
<ROWSET>
   <ROW num="1">
      <EMP_NO>7782</EMP_NO>
      <NAME>CLARK</NAME>
      <DEPT_NO>10</DEPT_NO>
   </ROW>
   <ROW num="2">
      <EMP_NO>7839</EMP_NO>
      <NAME>KING</NAME>
      <DEPT_NO>10</DEPT_NO>
   </ROW>
   <ROW num="3">
      <EMP_NO>7934</EMP_NO>
      <NAME>MILLER</NAME>
      <DEPT_NO>10</DEPT_NO>
   </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

O resultado é um elemento raiz chamado ROWSET, que contém uma lista de elementos ROW. Cada elemento ROW tem o número da linha como atributo e cada elemento ROW contém os elementos EMP_NO, NAME e DEPT_NO.

#### 3. Usando o XML-SQL Utility (XSU)

`XML-SQL Utility (XSU)` proporciona uma maneira simples de conseguir a transformação dos dados por meio do mapeamento de qualquer query para o `XML` e vice-versa. O `XSU` fornece a funcionalidade básica para obter e colocar dados de e para um banco de dados.

O `DBMS_XMLQUERY` e o `DBMS_XMLSAVE` são dois pacotes que oferecem suporte à geração e armazenamento de XML por meio de XML. Aqui vamos nos concentrar na geração de `XML`.

A geração de `XML` chamando a função `getXML()` resulta em um `CLOB` que contém o documento `XML`. Um identificador de contexto necessário na maioria das chamadas subseqüentes é criado na primeira etapa.

```
DECLARE
  queryCtx dbms_xmlquery.ctxType;
  result CLOB;
BEGIN
  -- set up the query context
  queryCtx := dbms_xmlquery.newContext(
    'SELECT empno "EMP_NO"
          , ename "NAME"
          , deptno "DEPT_NO"
       FROM emp
      WHERE deptno = 5'
  );
```

Se a definição de esquema DTD ou `XML` definiu explicitamente nomes de tags diferentes dos nomes das colunas, você pode alterar os nomes de tags ROW e ROWSET facilmente:

```
dbms_xmlquery.setRowTag(
      queryCtx
    , 'EMP'
  );
dbms_xmlquery.setRowSetTag(
      queryCtx
    , 'EMPSET'
  );
```

Ok, agora você está pronto para executar a consulta e gerar o resultado `XML` como `CLOB`. Um procedimento simples `printClobOut()` suporta a impressão de um `CLOB` na tela. Finalmente, o identificador de consulta deve ser fechado para liberar os recursos.

```
result := dbms_xmlquery.getXml(queryCtx);
printClobOut(result);
dbms_xmlquery.closeContext(queryCtx);
```

O resultado é algo como:

```
<?xml version = '1.0'?>
<EMPSET>
   <EMP num="1">
      <EMP_NO>7782</EMP_NO>
      <NAME>CLARK</NAME>
      <DEPT_NO>10</DEPT_NO>
   </EMP>
   <EMP num="2">
      <EMP_NO>7839</EMP_NO>
      <NAME>KING</NAME>
      <DEPT_NO>10</DEPT_NO>
   </EMP>
   <EMP num="3">
      <EMP_NO>7934</EMP_NO>
      <NAME>MILLER</NAME>
      <DEPT_NO>10</DEPT_NO>
   </EMP>
</EMPSET>
```

#### 4. Pacote XMLDOM

O pacote `XMLDOM` implementa a interface DOM (Document Object Model Interface), conforme definido pelas recomendações XML do W3C. Vamos seguir um exemplo simples para discutir o uso do pacote `XMLDOM`.

Na seção de declaração, você precisa de um conjunto de referências DOM. O identificador `DOMDocument` é o mais importante. Ele será usado na maioria das chamadas subseqüentes. Além disso, você precisa de diferentes identificadores de nó DOM para referenciar o nó principal, o nó raiz, o nó do usuário e o nó do item para cada elemento. O cursor seleciona os dados que serão expostos.

```
DECLARE
  doc xmldom.DOMDocument;
  main_node xmldom.DOMNode;
  root_node xmldom.DOMNode;
  user_node xmldom.DOMNode;
  item_node xmldom.DOMNode;
  root_elmt xmldom.DOMElement;
  item_elmt xmldom.DOMElement;
  item_text xmldom.DOMText;
  CURSOR get_users(p_deptno NUMBER) IS
    SELECT empno
         , ename
         , deptno
         , rownum
      FROM emp
     WHERE deptno = p_deptno;
```

Primeiro, você cria um novo identificador de documento. Em seguida, você cria o nó principal para este documento. O elemento raiz é chamado EMPSET e anexado como nó filho ao nó principal. O identificador retornado é usado como nó raiz para chamadas subseqüentes.

```
BEGIN
  doc := xmldom.newDOMDocument;
  main_node := xmldom.makeNode(doc);
  root_elmt := xmldom.createElement(
      doc
    , 'EMPSET'
  );
  root_node := xmldom.appendChild(
      main_node
    , xmldom.makeNode(root_elmt)
  );
```

Para cada registro encontrado na consulta, um novo elemento chamado EMP é criado. O número da linha é adicionado como atributo ao elemento. Este elemento é anexado como nó filho ao nó raiz. O identificador retornado é usado como nó do usuário para chamadas subseqüentes.

```
FOR get_users_rec IN get_users(10) LOOP
  item_elmt := xmldom.createElement(
      doc
    , 'EMP'
  );
  xmldom.setAttribute(
      item_elmt
    , 'num'
    , get_users_rec.rownum
  );
  user_node := xmldom.appendChild(
      root_node
    , xmldom.makeNode(item_elmt)
  );
```

Agora os elementos de texto podem ser adicionados ao documento DOM. Na primeira etapa, um novo elemento chamado EMP_NO é criado. Este elemento é anexado como nó filho ao nó do usuário. Na segunda etapa, é criado um nó de texto que contém os dados do registro, neste caso o número do empregado. Este nó de texto é anexado como nó filho ao nó do item.

```
item_elmt := xmldom.createElement(
    doc
  , 'EMP_NO'
);
item_node := xmldom.appendChild(
    user_node
  , xmldom.makeNode(item_elmt)
);
item_text := xmldom.createTextNode(
    doc
  , get_users_rec.empno
);
item_node := xmldom.appendChild(
    item_node
  , xmldom.makeNode(item_text)
);
```

O mesmo pode ser feito com os elementos de texto NAME e DEPT_NO.

Após todos os registros terem sido processados ​​e todos os dados terem sido carregados no documento DOM, eles podem ser, por exemplo, arquivados e seus recursos liberados:

```
  END LOOP;
  xmldom.writeToFile(
      doc
    , '/tmp/xml/docSample.xml'
  );
  xmldom.freeDocument(doc);
END;
```

Observe que o pacote `XMLDOM` pode gravar o arquivo `XML` em todos os locais acessíveis pelo usuário oracle do SO, independentemente do parâmetro de inicialização atual `UTL_FILE_DIR`. O arquivo resultante contém as seguintes linhas:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<EMPSET>
   <EMP num="1">
      <EMP_NO>7782</EMP_NO>
      <NAME>CLARK</NAME>
      <DEPT_NO>10</DEPT_NO>
   </EMP>
   <EMP num="2">
      <EMP_NO>7839</EMP_NO>
      <NAME>KING</NAME>
      <DEPT_NO>10</DEPT_NO>
   </EMP>
   <EMP num="3">
      <EMP_NO>7934</EMP_NO>
      <NAME>MILLER</NAME>
      <DEPT_NO>10</DEPT_NO>
   </EMP>
</EMPSET>
```

### Validação XSD

Para validar `XML` contra um `XSD`, primeiro você precisa registrar o `XSD`.

Neste exemplo, vamos usar o seguinte `XML`:

```
<order>
  <orderId> 1 </orderId>
  <customerId> 123 </customerId>
</order>
```

E a verificação está em conformidade com o seguinte `XSD`:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="order">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="orderId"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="customerId"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

(gerado usando http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html#ad-output )

Você o registra chamando `DBMS_XMLschema.registerSchema`:

```
begin
  dbms_xmlschema.registerSchema('order.xsd',
'<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="order">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="orderId"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="customerId"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>');
end;
/
```

Você pode então verificar se as instâncias `XMLType` estão em conformidade usando `isSchemaValid`. Se ele está em conformidade, então retorna 1, caso contrário retorna 0:

```
declare
  xml xmltype;
begin
  xml := xmltype('<order>
  <orderId>1</orderId>
  <customerId>123</customerId>
</order>');

  dbms_output.put_line(xml.isSchemaValid('order.xsd'));
end;
/
```

Mas isso não dá muita informação! Você pode obter mais detalhes sobre por que um documento não está em conformidade chamando `XMLType.schemaValidate`. Para usar isso, seu `XML` deve ter as informações corretas do espaço para nome.

Para fazer isso, adicione:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="order.xsd"
```

Faça isso e agora você receberá uma exceção se o `XML` não estiver em conformidade:

```
declare
  xml xmltype;
begin
  xml := xmltype('<order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="order.xsd">
  <orderId>1</orderId>
</order>');

  xmltype.schemaValidate(xml);
end;
/

ORA-31154: invalid XML document
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LSX-00213: only 0 occurrences of particle "customerId", minimum is 1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 354
ORA-06512: at line 8
31154. 00000 -  "invalid XML document" 
*Cause:    The XML document is invalid with respect to its XML Schema.
*Action:   Fix the errors identified and try again.
```

Com isso podemos criar uma procedure para validar o Schema XSD do XML:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE VALIDADOR_XML(pr_xml IN xmltype) IS
/*
 * Procedure valida o xml de acordo com um schema xsd predefinido
**/
BEGIN
  dbms_xmlschema.registerSchema('order.xsd',
        '<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
          <xs:element name="order">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="orderId"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="customerId"/>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>');

  IF pr_xml.isSchemaValid('order.xsd') THEN
    dbms_output.put_line ('XML VALIDO');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line ('XML INVALIDO');
    /*xmltype.schemaValidate(pr_xml);*/
  END IF;
END;
```

> Referências
>
> [Creating XML Documents with PL/SQL](https://www.akadia.com/services/ora_gen_xml.html)
>
> [Criando um arquivo XML com Oracle PL/SQL](https://www.viamais.net/blog/criando-um-arquivo-xml-com-oracle-plsql/)
>
> [Oracle® XML DB Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10790/toc.htm)
>
> [Validar documentos XML com o esquema XML no Oracle PL / SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45077438/validate-xml-documents-with-xml-schema-in-oracle-pl-sql)
>
> [Transformando e validando dados XMLType](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb08tra.htm)
>
> [Ask TOM - Como usar isSchemaValid() no oracle 11gr2 para validar XML
>   contra o esquema XSD?](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9529444000346870090)
>
> [Valide XML no ORACLE contra um XSD usando DBMS_XMLSCHEMA e
>   XMLTYPE.SCHEMAVALIDATE](http://when-others-then-null.blogspot.com/2013/01/validate-xml-in-oracle-against-xsd.html)

Answer (score 0):

Acabei de sair de um projeto que gerava um xml com base em um base no Oracle. Para isso utilizei SQLX --> https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sqlxml-sqlx-generating-xml-content-using-sql. As regras do xsd que tive que respetiar, fiz tudo na mão.

Comment: Amigo ,se eu tivesse o código não teria tópico , pedi um exemplo ou a documentação.

Comment: @Edvaldo Costa , grato , mas como fez para aplicar o xml ao schema ?